# Database design for ticket booking system

Tags: database, database-design, 3nf

I would like to create a database for a ticket booking system for a small cinema.

Do you have any comments/suggestions for the project below? Do the tables meet the third normal form rules?

[image]

Comment: Can you construct a functional GUI/webpage using this database?  Are you duplicating data in your database?  In other words, you test your design by writing SQL queries that make logical sense.

Comment: there missing seat class , seat no , booking date